# I am unable to get any sort of output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, relational-operators

This is my python code: Only output that i get in the end is *"True"*
Why am i not receiving output for others? Please help.
I am using jupyter notebook on visual studio code. Kernel: Python 3.9 64-bit

```
# RELATIONAL OPERATORS
num1 = 10
num2 = 0
num3 = 10
str1 = "good"
str2 = "life"

# Equals to
num1 == num2
str1 == str2

# Not equal to
num1 != num2
str1 != str2
num1 != num3

# Greater Than
num1 > num2
str1 > str2

# Less Than
num1 < num3
str2 < str1

# Greater than or equal to
num1 >= num2
num2 >= num3
str1 >= str2

#Less then or equal to
num1 <= num2
num2 <= num3
str1 <= str2
```

Comment: You are not using print, write these expressions in `print()`

Comment: It may be worth noting to the extreme beginner, depending on where the source code came from/tutorial you read, that this [will show output in the REPL for every statement](https://www.learnpython.dev/01-introduction/02-requirements/05-vs-code/04-the-repl-in-vscode/) because that's what the REPL _does_. The REPL starts with `>>>`. In a complete program, you need to tell Python to show you the output.

Comment: Ah yes, it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to wrap each of the statements in print()

```
num1 = 10
num2 = 0
num3 = 10
str1 = "good"
str2 = "life"

print(num1 == num2)
print(str1 == str2)
# so on and so forth
```